# Send name trough smtp header with Mule ESB

Tags: java, mule, esb

We are using Mule ESB to send emails with smtp:connector and smtp:endpoint. I've never worked with mule before. The task is to send the name of a person trough smtp header FROM field, so that person's name masks generic email that we are sending with, basically "My Name" . I've tried this exact format with mule but it throws some malformed exception. I know it is possible to do this with java but can't seem to find a property in mule xml file. Maybe its possible to hijack smtp:endpoint and write custom java code that will do this?

ps. I am not allowed to give you any code :(

Comment: Could you please share dummy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing MEL expression in **from** attribute of SMTP outbound endpoint, like below:

```
<smtp:outbound-endpoint from="#[message.inboundProperties['smtp.from']]" host="..." port="..." connector-ref="..." to="#[message.inboundProperties['smtp.to']]"  subject="#[message.inboundProperties['smtp.subject']]" cc="#[message.inboundProperties['smtp.cc']]" bcc="#[message.inboundProperties['smtp.bcc']]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Send SMTP"></smtp:outbound-endpoint>
```